# Little brown spots on my variegated rubber tree

Tags: plant-health

[image]

Hi

I have these little brown spots. When I google mostly the issue is with browning leaves (from the sides)

I’m not exactly sure what these are from. They were propagated in water and recently been moved to fresh soil. 
Watered it-with drainage holes and a very mulchy soil. 
I put it next to a south eastern window. Since it’s vairegated I thought it needed more light. (I live in the northern hemisphere)

Is it sun damage? Or something in the roots? It’s literally been less than a week with the transfer from water to soil.